# The difference between UITableView HeaderView and UITableViewCell when using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhaBV.png)

```
class CornerCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var exLabel: UILabel!
    
    private var borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private var myType: RoundedTableViewCellType = .middle
    
    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
            let inset: CGFloat = 20
            var frame = newValue
            frame.origin.x += inset
            frame.size.width -= 2 * inset
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
    
    var borderColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    
    var radius: CGFloat = 6.0 {
        didSet {
            type = myType
        }
    }
    
    var type: RoundedTableViewCellType = .middle {
        didSet {
            myType = type
            switch type {
            case .first:
                layer.cornerRadius = radius
                layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
            case .last:
                layer.cornerRadius = radius
                layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
            case .single:
                layer.cornerRadius = radius
                layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
            case .middle:
                layer.cornerRadius = 0
                layer.maskedCorners = []
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let r = radius
        var bPath = UIBezierPath()
        
        let ptTopLeft = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        let ptTopRight = CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: 0.0)
        let ptBotRight = CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height)
        let ptBotLeft = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: bounds.height)
        
        switch type {
        case .first:
            bPath.move(to: ptBotLeft)
            bPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopLeft.x, y: ptTopLeft.y + r))

            bPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopLeft.x + r, y: ptTopLeft.y),
                               controlPoint: ptTopLeft)

            bPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopRight.x - r, y: ptTopRight.y))

            bPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopRight.x, y: ptTopRight.y + r),
                               controlPoint: ptTopRight)

            bPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ptBotRight.x, y: ptBotRight.y))

        case .last:
            bPath.move(to: ptTopLeft)
            
            bPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ptBotLeft.x, y: ptBotLeft.y - r))
            bPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: ptBotLeft.x + r, y: ptBotLeft.y), controlPoint: ptBotLeft)
            
            bPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ptBotRight.x - r, y: ptBotRight.y))
            bPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: ptBotRight.x, y: ptBotRight.y - r), controlPoint: ptBotRight)
            
            bPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopRight.x, y: ptTopRight.y))
        case .single:
            bPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: r)

        case .middle:
            bPath.move(to: ptTopLeft)
            bPath.addLine(to: ptBotLeft)
            bPath.addLine(to: ptBotRight)
            bPath.addLine(to: ptTopRight)
        }
        
        borderLayer.path = bPath.cgPath
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)

        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        // default values
        borderColor = .black
        borderWidth = 1.0
    }
}
```

```
class CustomHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!
    
    private var borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private var myType: RoundedTableViewCellType = .middle
    
    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
            let inset: CGFloat = 20
            var frame = newValue
            frame.origin.x += inset
            frame.size.width -= 2 * inset
            super.frame = frame
        }
    }
    
    var borderColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }
    
    var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    
    var radius: CGFloat = 6.0 {
        didSet {
            type = myType
        }
    }
    
    var type: RoundedTableViewCellType = .middle {
        didSet {
            myType = type
            switch type {
            case .first:
                layer.cornerRadius = radius
                layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
            case .last:
                layer.cornerRadius = radius
                layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
            case .single:
                layer.cornerRadius = radius
                layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
            case .middle:
                layer.cornerRadius = 0
                layer.maskedCorners = []
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let r = radius
        var bPath = UIBezierPath()
        
        let ptTopLeft = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        let ptTopRight = CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: 0.0)
        let ptBotRight = CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height)
        let ptBotLeft = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: bounds.height)
        
        switch type {
        case .first:
            bPath.move(to: ptBotLeft)
            bPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopLeft.x, y: ptTopLeft.y + r))

            bPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopLeft.x + r, y: ptTopLeft.y),
                               controlPoint: ptTopLeft)

            bPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopRight.x - r, y: ptTopRight.y))

            bPath.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: ptTopRight.x, y: ptTopRight.y + r),
                               controlPoint: ptTopRight)

            bPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: ptBotRight.x, y: ptBotRight.y))

        case .last:
            bPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                 byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight],
                                 cornerRadii: CGSize(width: r, height: r))

        case .single:
            bPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: r)

        case .middle:
            bPath.move(to: ptTopLeft)
            bPath.addLine(to: ptBotLeft)
            bPath.addLine(to: ptBotRight)
            bPath.addLine(to: ptTopRight)
        }
        
        borderLayer.path = bPath.cgPath
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() {
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)

        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        // default values
        borderColor = .black
        borderWidth = 1.0
    }
}
```

I used same code, but headerView borderWidth is thicker than cell. (headerView's type is 'first' & cell's type is 'middle'and 'last')

I don't know why this result was.

I want to draw same borderWidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borders are drawn on "center lines."

Suppose you used a borderWidth of 8 ... you will get 4-points *inside* the frame and 4-points *outside* the frame.

By default, a `UITableViewCell` has `.clipsToBounds = true`, but a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` has `.clipsToBounds = false`.

So, the *outside* part of the border is **visible** on your header view.

You can fix this by setting `.clipsToBounds` to the same value on both classes. Try it with true, then try it with false, and see which you prefer.